# Move files into folders with common words among the files and pre-existing folders

Tags: batch-file

I have some files

```
1x01 La figlia di Elisa.mkv
1x04 La figlia di Elisa.avi
....
7x20 L&O - I Due Volti Della Giustizia.mp4
7x21 L&O - I Due Volti Della Giustizia.mp4
...
```

and I have 2 folders like

```
La figlia di Elisa - stagione 1
L&O - I Due Volti Della Giustizia - 20 stagioni
```

I try to move files in this way

```
La figlia di Elisa - stagione 1
           |
           |
           +--- 1x01 La figlia di Elisa.mkv
           +--- 1x04 La figlia di Elisa.avi
           
L&O - I Due Volti Della Giustizia - 20 stagioni
           |
           |
           +---- 7x20 L&O - I Due Volti Della Giustizia.mp4
           +---- 7x21 L&O - I Due Volti Della Giustizia.mp4
```

but this script fails

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd %1
for /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%a in (`dir /b /a:-d`) do (
    set "_file=%%a"
    for /D %%b in (*) do (
        if NOT "x!_file:%%b=!" == "x!_file!" (
            move "%%a" "%%b"
        )
    )
)
popd
```

It move files only if I have folders renamed in this way

```
La figlia di Elisa
L&O - I Due Volti Della Giustizia
```

Comment: The script does not **fail**.  It is doing exactly what you programmed it to do.  You already know the problem is that the full folder name is not completely within the file name.  So renaming the folder makes it work.  Now we could certainly brute force a solution for these two particular folders but I highly doubt these are the only two folders and file names that you are dealing with.  So you are going to have to provide technical specification on how the matching can be performed to accommodate all your file and folder names.

Comment: As Squashman said...
Your code is not working because the directory name strings are not inside the filenames.
For example, the file is `"1x01 La figlia di Elisa.mkv"` and the folder is `"La figlia di Elisa - stagione 1"`.
Because of `" - stagioni 1"` it does not proceed to `"1x01.mkv"`.
As it does not have a default delimiter, it is difficult to deal with.
`"L&O - I Due Volti Della Giustizia - 20 stagioni"`, for example, has two dashes `-`.

I suggest you rename the folders to something easier or look for another code way, Maybe getting `%folder:~7,-14%` substring.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is this

```
# Create a hashtable by mapping each name pattern to its corresponding folder path
$destinationFolders = @{
    "La figlia di Elisa" = "C:\temp\La figlia di Elisa - stagione 1"
    "L&O - I Due Volti Della Giustizia" = "C:\temp\L&O - I Due Volti Della Giustizia - 20 stagioni"
}

# Get the list of files present in C:\temp
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\temp

# Iterate through each file
foreach ($file in $files) {
    # If the file is not a folder
    if (-not $file.PSIsContainer) {
        # Iterate through each name pattern in the hashtable
        foreach ($folderName in $destinationFolders.Keys) {
            # If the file name contains the naming pattern
            if ($file.Name -match $folderName) {
                # Move the file to the corresponding folder
                Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $destinationFolders[$folderName]
            }
        }
    }
}
```